# CSS: Is there any difference between these two parts?

Tags: css

Is there any difference? I do not see. The first doesn't work, the second works.
It is the same file (other files are not touched).

[image: CSS brain torment]

If I comment with `/* */` the first part (the second will be used by web-browser), all works, but if I comment with `/* */` the second part (the first will be used by web-browser), nothing works.

Is it magic?

I've tried it on different web-browsers. I was resetting the browsers cleaning all their caches. But... no result.

May be there are some utilities exist that can do a binary comparison? Could you please give me examples of such programs?

UPDATE: I apologise, the screenshot is little mislead. I use only one of the parts when I do testing (one of the parts is commented with `/* */` when I test).

**UPDATE 2: look at this, more full part of the style.css file:**
[image: more bigger part of the code]

Now look, I've added `display: none` to the original `#items` block. *There is no affect in the web-browsers!* (do not say me about cache, I've tried on different browsers, different laptops, was reseting and cleaning all the caches of web-browsers). Just notice that `display: none` has been added:
[image: #items part only]

*All works like before, like we even didn't write `display: none`.*

Now let's try the following:

[image: additional #items part]

*It works! (`display: none` works)*
*Why?*

Comment: How do you know which rule the browser is using? They're exactly the same, so technically the latter should override the former - but why does it matter?

Comment: I would suggest there is a larger issue at work, such as a piece of code in between the two rules that changes some of the properties.

Comment: @Andy E: No, I do not use both of them at the same time :) I apologise, the screenshot is mislead :) I use only one of these two parts when I test the code.

Comment: @Karpie: no, the second is right next to the first. The magic is why commenting with `/* */` the different parts causes different result?

Comment: @Azat: So the larger issue then is, define 'nothing works'.

Comment: Why dont you remove one of them altogether and check?

Comment: I've updated the topic and wrote that I use only one part when I test. One of the parts when I test is always commented with `/* */`

Comment: There is *some larger issue* at work here. If you could manage it, a live test page would make this really easy to debug.

Comment: So maybe you have `/*` opening comment somewhere before the first block, and when you comment that code, you also end the earlier comment block.

Comment: My guess is that you have some characters in the first that aren't what they seem. We would probably need the code itself and not a picture of it to figure anything out... If you look for a hex editor, then you should be able to find many programs to help you compare the two blocks.

Comment: @jswolf19: yes, I think the problem is here. Ok, I have to find the hex editor. Could you suggest me some, please?

Comment: @Azat: I can't think of a single plausible scenario where in the CSS in your original question, you somehow managed to get a [lookalike character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack) which is breaking it. It just doesn't sound right.

Comment: @thirtydot: may be. I'm seeking for hex-comparing programs right now...

Comment: Copy/past all your document into a new document ; and remove all the 2 blocks that causes problem ; then rewrite manually the first one ; copy/past this rewritten first block just after. If you do the same test, do you have the same problem again ?

Comment: @Cedrick: I've done this right now. No result. Wait for the update of the answer, please. I want to show something interesting.

Comment: @Azat: I haven't downloaded one to use recently, so I'm not the best person to recommend one, but for this, you don't need any major features, so any one will do.

Comment: I've updated the post (see UPDATE 2 at the end) that shows some interesting things.

Comment: @Azat: See my previous comment: "There is *some larger issue* at work here. If you could manage it, a live test page would make this really easy to debug."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the one mystic character (on line 81 on the screenshot). I've only been not using an option 'Show invisible characters' in my code editor.

[image: CSS with invisible characters]

I've removed this character and the problem was solved. I don't really know, how this character (ASCII 0x8 (“backspace”)) appeared here.

Thank you all the people who responded on this question and advised different solutions.

UPD: I've created the related question, about putting 0x08 character on MacBook into a text: [How can I put 0x08 ascii character using MacBook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946056/how-can-i-put-0x08-ascii-character-using-macbook)

Comment: Good job on finding it. I'm going to point out that for future questions of this kind, you should really provide a test page. I, along with other people here, could have found that in less than five minutes, given your description of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, the decision of giving here only screenshots was my fault.

Comment: Does anybody know how this character could appear here? (I use MacBook and the "Coda" editor. There is even no ability to press Alt + 08 on MacBook). How it could happen?

Comment: You probably copied some code from another source into your document, bringing along this rogue character.

Comment: @coreyward, the problem is that all the code is written by me and I don't know, how it could appear. Anyway, I've created the special question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946056/how-can-i-put-0x08-ascii-character-using-macbook

Comment: @coreyward, in fact you partly right. I've copied this part from my another code that is also written by me. But it does not have such characters — I've rechecked it know. Really mistically, how 0x08 appeared during only “copy & paste”.

Answer (score 1):

if the first part is in the beginning of the file:
may be you use [UTF-8 with BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Byte_order_mark) encoding.
change the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM or ASCII.

BOM add three bytes at the start of the file, and many old programs\systems sees "ï»¿#items" in your file.

Comment: It is not the beginning of the css file.