# How can I put 0x08 ascii character using MacBook?

Tags: macos, ide, character-encoding, editor, coda

I'm writing this question because one little invisible problem has taken from me hours and hours of dummy searchings, and the time just has been wasted (here is that question: [CSS: Is there any difference between these two parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944067/css-is-there-any-difference-between-these-two-parts))

**Does anybody know** how the character 0x08 ("backspace" in ASCII) can be written into a text using a MacBook and a simple IDE (I use the "Coda")?

There is no ability to press Alt + 08 on MacBook (there is no digital keys part on the MacBook's keyboard).

How it can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy & paste it from anywhere? Because the only way I know - apart from what SCFrench suggested - is to enable this in Terminal by typing:

`stty erase` <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

Comment: How “copy & paste” is related to this? I'm asking because I've used it. (I copied my own code from one my file to another my file). How could 0x08 character appeared during this action?

Comment: Well, you might have seen similar effects with newlines that are different for the various operating systems (ie. does a line end with \n or \r or CR or LF…) so it might be possible (though I have not seen this specific problem before) that by copying and pasting between two files opened in different encodings (eg. one in Latin1, one in UTF-8) you created the \b (resp. 0x08) character by accident.

Comment: @Asmus: Great! I supposed that the reason exactly in different charsets. **But why `\b`?** What's the mechanism of appearing \b? We have only \r (0x0d) or/and \n (0x0a).

Comment: The newlines were meant as an example; in your case, it´s all about the backspace. The Ascii equivalent of 0x08 in different notations is \b, BS, ^H, backspace.

Comment: @Asmus: ok. The answer is that we could expect anything when use converting from one charset to another? :)

Comment: The low 128 bytes of the UTF-8 charset is mapped directly to ASCII (in the Latin1 variant, if you prefer), so that should not cause weird things. I can also suggest another clue: what if you have accidentally copied a _part_ of an UTF-8 character? It can easily contain any byte, including 0x08. (Also, there are a lot of control sequences. A partial list can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(v=vs.80).aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the easiest way, but:

1. In the Keyboard system preferences panel, check "Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar".
2. Find the Keyboard menu bar icon (on the right side of the menu bar), click it, and select "Show Character Viewer".
3. In the Characters window that appears, find the "View" pop up menu and select "Code Tables".
4. Select the Unicode coding tab.
5. In the middle section where all the characters are displayed, click on the entry for 0008 (it will be blank, but the Name: field will say "BACKSPACE").
6. Click the Insert button in the same window.

Since the character is non-printable, it doesn't actually show anything in the text editor, but (at least in TextEdit) you will see that you have to hit the left or right arrow key more than once to move past it. I also confirmed by dumping the file in hex that it contains a 08 byte.

You could also use this technique to set up a Text Substitution in the Text tab of the Language & Text system preference panel.

Comment: Is there a method to paste this character using only keyboard?

Comment: May this character appear when we do “copy & paste” the code, which does NOT contain such characters?

Comment: Ah, I think I may have slightly misunderstood the question. I thought you were asking how to do it, not, how could it have happened. Clearly it doesn't seem likely that someone "accidentally" performed these 6 steps...

Comment: yeah, the key question is “How it can happen?”

Answer (score 0):

Shift + Up Arrow + Delete/Backspace. It's a bug.

http://www.openradar.me/5288750