# Gzip compressed css file with php header, first css line does not work

Tags: php, css, header, compression, gzip

I am using gzip to compress my files so I need to add the following code to the top.

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
header("content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
header("cache-control: must-revalidate");
header("expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 1000)." GMT");
```

The problem is now that the first line of css code in my file does not work. e.g.

```
body{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

using this the text would be bold but not red.

Looking forward to an advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

From the comments, it turned out to be because:

> the php code was inserting something
>   into the css file.

Probably either:

- an unprintable character similar to this:  [CSS: Is there any difference between these two parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944067/css-is-there-any-difference-between-these-two-parts/4945225#4945225)
- or a [UTF-8 BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168612/divs-appearing-different-on-different-browsers/6168758#6168758).

---

The `font-color` property does not exist.

Use [`color: red`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color) instead.

If the text is indeed bold, then your CSS file is working, so there shouldn't be any more problems.

Although I think the last line of your PHP should be:

```
header("expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 1000)." GMT");
```

Comment: Well, I did edit it in the post, but that definitely was not the problem. I did use correct css when testing. It really just does not work for the first line. Removing the php code the first line works, if the code is there it does not. Any other ideas?

Comment: I can't think of a single scenario where `body{color:red;font-weight:bold}` would result in "not red", bold text. If the entire selector was being ignored ("not red" *and* not bold) that would make sense. There's either something you're not putting in your question, or some very weird issue, like this perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944067/css-is-there-any-difference-between-these-two-parts Also, what happens if you do `body{font-weight:bold;color:red}` - do you get text that is not bold, but is red?

Comment: If you could make a `.zip` file or similar containing a complete test case, that would help.

Comment: Thanks dude, it was the weird issue case. Apparently the php code was inserting something into the css file. I redid the header part and it works like a blase now. thanks.
If you could post this part as an answer I could check it as a correct answer.